# Is there a site show cloudstack source code contribution by companies like openstack community heartbeat

Tags: apache-cloudstack

Is there a site show cloudstack source code contribution by companies like openstack community heartbeat
http://www.stackalytics.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sebastien Goasguen's [Update on Apache CloudStack Community Analysis](http://sebgoa.blogspot.co.uk/search/label/analysis) will give you a sense of the contributions.

However, you won't see a lot of companies:  AFAIK, Apache accepts contributions from individuals and not corporations.

This isn't a programming question, so I have posted the question on the [CloudStack developers mailing list](http://cloudstack.apache.org/mailing-lists.html)

Update:  [Feedback from Apache CloudStack developer mailinglist](http://markmail.org/message/4srf7gbqj26sarqf)